# final array instance variable in a java class and resetting a reference

Tags: java, arrays, final

I tried out the following code,which has a `final` instance variable called `data`.This is instantiated in the constructor using an `int[]` argument.If an element of the int[] array changes ,the change is reflected in the instance variable and is shown in the `show()'s` output.However,if I set the external array to null ,or to a new array,the change is not reflected in the show() output.

why does this happen? if the external array is changed by ext[0]=x ,the change is shown in the inst.variable.It doesnot happen if the ext reference is set to a new object.

```
public class MutabilityTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] ext =  new int[] {1,2,3,4,5};
        FMutable xmut = new FMutable(ext);
        mut.show();    //shows [1,2,3,4,5]
        System.out.println("changed ext array");
        ext[0] = 99;
        System.out.println("ext:"+Arrays.toString(ext)); //[99,2,3,4,5]
        mut.show();    //shows [99,2,3,4,5]
        System.out.println("set ext array to new");
        ext = new int[]{8,8,8,8} 
        System.out.println("ext:"+Arrays.toString(ext)); //[8,8,8,8]
        mut.show();//expected [8,8,8,8] but got [99,2,3,4,5]
        ext = null;
        System.out.println("ext:"+Arrays.toString(ext)); //null
        mut.show(); //shows same [99,2,3,4,5]
    }
}
class FMutable{
    private final int[] data;
    public FMutable(int[] indata){
    this.data = indata;
    }
    public void show(){
    System.out.println("XMutable:"+Arrays.toString(this.data));
    }
}
```

Comment: in java..
Object is paassed by refrence and data types using passed by value...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `data` being final, or a field elsewhere. You can see the exact same effect much more simply:

```
int[] x = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int[] y = x;

y[0] = 10;
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x)); // 10, 2, 3, 4, 5
y = new int[] { 3, 3, 3, };
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x)); // 10, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

It's important to differentiate between *variables*, their values, and objects. Think of a variable as being like a piece of paper. It can have a primitive value written on it, or a house address.

The line:

```
int[] y = x;
```

or in your sample code:

```
this.data = indata;
```

just copies what's written on one piece of paper onto a new piece of paper. That's just the address of the "house" (the array object in this case).

Now those two pieces of paper are themselves independent - changing what's written on one of them doesn't change what's written on the other. However, if you go to the house by following the address on one piece of paper, make a change (e.g. paint the front door) and then go to the house by following the address on the *other* piece of paper (while they're still the same) then yes, you'll see the freshly painted door. That's what you're seeing when you make a change to the array itself.

Comment: I've seen that explanation earlier. Yes, I remember I saw it in one of your earlier answer too with the same example. Nice one :)

Comment: @RohitJain: Yes, I keep meaning to write it up in an article or blog post some time, so I can just refer to it :)

Answer (score 1):

`ext` is just another reference pointing to the same memory location as `data` instance array. If you set `ext` to null it will only set the `ext` reference to `null` and not the `data` array.

Answer (score 1):

```
final int[] data
```

This means your array obejct is final(you can initialize once and can not change after that) but `index's` are not.

Which you have initialized through constructor.

```
public FMutable(int[] indata){
    this.data = indata;
}
```

*`ext` is another reference which poitning to the same object.* Any change on same object also will effect on `final data` field as both referring the same `Object`.

But as reference data is final you can not reinitalize. And `ext = new int[]{8,8,8,8}` will create a new array and ext will pointing to that.

Answer (score 1):

`ext = new int[]{8,8,8,8}` creates a new array for the variable `ext` but does not affect the field `data` in your object. Note that the same effect would occure if `data` wasn't final!

`final` only means that you can set the reference once, however the object can still be manipulated.